# Calculating the circumference and area of a circle

Tags: java, beginner

This simple program uses `Scanner` to obtain a radius from the user, then calculates and outputs the circumference and area.

Questions:

1. Is it customary in Java to place a function call inside of a `println()`, or is it better to put the returned value into a separate variable and then display that?
2. Should I consider implementing input-validation for practice as this is a toy program?
3. Am I correct in making the calculation functions `static`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Circle {

    public static double getCircumference(double radius) {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public static double getArea(double radius) {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double radius = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Circumference: ");
        System.out.println(getCircumference(radius));
        System.out.println("Area: ");
        System.out.println(getArea(radius));

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

> ```
> 5.5
> Circumference: 
> 34.55751918948772
> Area: 
> 95.03317777109123
> ```

Comment: 1. Could you attach some sample output?  2. Why restrict the radius to `int`?  The class name, `Circle`, suggests something more general.

Comment: @GraniteRobert: It doesn't have to be restricted; I just thought about an `int` at first.  I can change that, along with providing sample output.

Comment: I wondered if you intended separate lines in the output.  I thought I was misunderstanding my JAVA.

Comment: @GraniteRobert: I actually like them on separate lines, but I didn't take the time to find out how to do it.  I suppose it's another minor thing anyway.

Comment: Java needs to catch up with the times and add a Tau constant. http://www.tauday.com/tau-manifesto

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it customary in Java to place a function call inside of a println(), or is it better to put the returned value into a separate variable and then display that?

This is something I would say is primarily opinion based. For this little app, I think it's fine to put the <s>function</s> *method* call inside a `println`.

When it comes to more complex things, it is usually better to do the calculation separately from the output (or most importantly logging), because you don't want your program behavior to change when you remove a `System.out.println` or logging statement.

---

> Should I consider implementing input-validation for practice as this is a toy program?

I don't see any need to use input-validation when you're using `nextInt` on the `Scanner`. Perhaps you'd want to avoid a negative size, and either throw an exception or show an error message to the user, but that's probably it.

---

> Am I correct in making the calculation functions static?

Yes, absolutely. I see no reason for why they should not be static. Given the usefulness of them, it is a good idea to have them `public` as well (which you have).

---

Feature-request: You're currently not prompting for any input which might make the user confused. A simple `System.out.println("Enter radius:");` would be nice to have.

---

Overall, your code looks perfectly fine. A minor *minor* <sub>minor</sub> nitpick is that you're writing one space more than necessary here:

```
System.out.println("Circumference: ");
System.out.println("Area: ");
```

Another <sub>minor</sub> nitpick is that your Scanner variable could be named either `scanner` or `input` instead. (Even though `sc` is a quite normal variable name for a `Scanner`) #perfectionist-naming.

Comment: Thanks for the nitpick. ;-) I forgot that this is displayed on separate lines, so that extra space is useless.

Answer (score 12):

Creating a `Circle` object would probably be more idiomatic Java.  The code would read a bit more fluently (for example, `circle.getCircumference()`).  It also gives you a good place to validate that the radius is nonnegative.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle {
    private final double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
         if (radius < 0) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
         this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getCircumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            double radius = sc.nextDouble();
            Circle circle = new Circle(radius);

            System.out.println("Circumference: ");
            System.out.println(circle.getCircumference());
            System.out.println("Area: ");
            System.out.println(circle.getArea());
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of minor points as well:

- `import java.lang.Math` is unnecessary, because `java.lang.*` are always available already.
- Since Java 7, try-with-resources gives you a way to automatically close auto-closeable objects like `Scanner`.
- Neither your code nor my code above checks that there is a `double` to read at all.  If the input is garbage, then a `java.util.InputMismatchException` will be thrown, which is unhandled.

Comment: Ah, so I *wasn't* creating an actual `Circle` class.  I should've known otherwise since this is sort of the same as in C++.  It looks like I was actually using free functions.

Comment: I would guess that for someone with good education and experience, they did whatever they did because of convenient for the purpose at that moment. You are sadly mistaken if you think one person doesn't know how to do things like this. It will be object oriented when it needs to be object oriented and scalable.

Answer (score 8):

I actually didn't like having each label and result displayed on separated lines, and instead wanted to have each value on separate lines like this:

> ```
> 5.5
> Circumference: 34.55751918948772
> Area: 95.03317777109123
> ```

I've discovered that `print()` accomplishes this, alongside `println()` for newlines.

I've also incorporated @Simon's suggestion regarding a user input prompt.

```java
System.out.print("Input radius: ");

// ...

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Circumference = ");
System.out.println(circle.getCircumference());
System.out.print("Area = ");
System.out.print(circle.getArea());
```

With this, I get the following output (using the same radius):

> ```
> Input radius: 5.5
>
> Circumference = 34.55751918948772
> Area = 95.03317777109123
> ```

Comment: I would use `:` instead of `=` from a "conventions" point of view.